# Silent Remote Notification - App Killed status iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios10, remote-notifications

I am integrating Silent Remote notification in my application, all is working fine. But the issue is when my app is in killed state or not running state then no application delegate methods are getting triggered.

**When I see in device log I can see:** 
*"Springboard : High Priority Push:   - App killed"*.

Can anybody please help me out.

1. I have implemented

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Swift.Void)
   ```
2. When app is in background and foreground state then above method is getting trigger.
3. I have enabled back ground  fetch and Remote notification in the capabilities

**Note:** 
I am sending silent push notification through terminal like this :

```
apn push <device_token> --certificate <path_of_pem_file> --payload '{"aps":{"content-available":1}}'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: content-available =1 only work when your app in background.

Comment: You can't do anything if the app is killed sadly